# Creating permanent WMI event using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm trying to create WMI Object using PowerShell, i read many articles and blogs related to this topic, all were good enough to let me understand the WMI structure and how it works.
The problem here is that i can't figure out what's wrong with the below code:

```
#Creating a new event filter 
$instanceFilter = ([WMICLASS]"\\.\root\subscription:__EventFilter").CreateInstance()
$instanceFilter.QueryLanguage = "WQL"
$instanceFilter.Query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace" 
$instanceFilter.Name = "EventFilter1" 
$result = $instanceFilter.Put() 
$newFilter = $result.Path 


#Creating a new event consumer 
$instanceConsumer = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:LogFileEventConsumer").CreateInstance() 
$instanceConsumer.Name = "EventConsumer1" 
$instanceConsumer.FileName = "C:\Scripts\Process_Log.log" 
$instanceConsumer.Text = "New process has been created: %TargetInstance.ProcessName%" 
$result = $instanceConsumer.Put() 
$newConsumer = $result.Path 


#Bind filter and consumer 
$instanceBinding = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:__FilterToConsumerBinding").CreateInstance() 
$instanceBinding.Filter = $newFilter 
$instanceBinding.Consumer = $newConsumer 
$result = $instanceBinding.Put()
```

I'm creating the instance filter and consumer, then bind them to create the instance, that will write a log to C:\Scripts\Process_Log.log each time a process starts.

I can find the object when running Get-WMIObject but it's not working and nothing is written to my log file.

NOTE: I'm running this on an updated Win 10 machine